# How to change the swap interval of QGLWidget

Tags: qt5

I am promoting a widet in UI to QGlWidget and in the constructor of QGLWidget i am assigning swap intervals to 0.

But that does not affect the widget it still shows the value of swap interval as 1.

How can i change the swap value to 0.

The platform is windows.

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget * parent): QGLWidget(parent) {
  QGLFormat format;
  format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
  format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
  format.setSampleBuffers(true);
  format.setSamples(4);
  format.setSwapInterval(0);
  this -> setFormat(format);
  makeCurrent();

  qDebug() << "Swap Interval +++++++   " << this -> format().swapInterval();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that in Windows the `WGL_EXT_swap_control` extension has to be present for this to work.

see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglformat.html#setSwapInterval

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there is OpenGL extension method `wglSwapIntervalEXT`.
From the post by b2b3 http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=360862:

> If you are working on Windows you have to use extensions to use
> `wglSwapIntervalExt` function. It is
> defined in wglext.h. You will also want to
> download glext.h file.
> In wglext file all entry points for Windows specific extensions are
> declared. All such functions start
> with prefix wgl.
> To get more info about all published extensions you can look into
> OpenGL Extension Registry.
>
> `wglSwapIntervalEXT` is from `WGL_EXT_swap_control` extension. It
> lets you specify minimum number of
> frames before each buffer swap.
> Usually it is used for vertical
> synchronization (if you set swap
> interval to 1). More info about whole
> extension can be found here.
> Before using this function you need query whether you card has
> support for `WGL_EXT_swap_control` and
> then obtain pointer to the function
> using `wglGetProcAddress` function.
>
> To test for support of given extension you can use function like this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include "wglext.h"

bool WGLExtensionSupported(const char *extension_name)
{
    // this is pointer to function which returns pointer to string with list of all wgl extensions
    PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGEXTPROC _wglGetExtensionsStringEXT = NULL;

    // determine pointer to wglGetExtensionsStringEXT function
    _wglGetExtensionsStringEXT = (PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringEXT");

    if (strstr(_wglGetExtensionsStringEXT(), extension_name) == NULL)
    {
        // string was not found
        return false;
    }

    // extension is supported
    return true;
}
```

> To initialize your function pointers you need to:

```cpp
PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC       wglSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;
PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = NULL;

if (WGLExtensionSupported("WGL_EXT_swap_control"))
{
    // Extension is supported, init pointers.
    wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");

    // this is another function from WGL_EXT_swap_control extension
    wglGetSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLGETSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("wglGetSwapIntervalEXT");
}
```

> Then you can use these pointers as any other pointer to function. To enable vync you can call `wglSwapIntervalEXT(1)`, to disable it you call `wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)`.
>
> To get current swap interval you need to call `wglGetSwapIntervalEXT()`.